# How to resolve transitive dependencies of local modules

Tags: go, go-modules

Inside some random folder, there are 3 folders a, b, c. Each of these folders contain a mod file.

The mod files contains are the following .

go.mod inside a

```
module a

go 1.13
```

go.mod inside b

```
module b
go 1.13
require a v0.0.0
replace a v0.0.0 => ./../a
```

go.mod inside c

```
module c
go 1.13
require b v0.0.0
replace b v0.0.0 => ./../b
```

Module b throws no error. But module c throws error

```
go: b@v0.0.0 requires
a@v0.0.0: unrecognized import path "a" (import path does not begin with hostname)
```

Every module must have a dot(.) in their module name.

'Some random folder' changes to example.com. Now example.com named folder contains all the a.b.c folders. Here is how the modules look now

Module A looks like

```
module example.com/a
go 1.13
```

Module B looks like

```
module example.com/b
go 1.13
require example.com/a v0.0.0
replace example.com/a v0.0.0 => ../a
```

Module C looks like

```
module example.com/c
go 1.13
require example.com/b v0.0.0
replace example.com/b v0.0.0 => ../b
```

Too bad!   Error!

```
go: example.com/b@v0.0.0 requires
example.com/a@v0.0.0: unrecognized import path "example.com/a" (https fetch: Get 
https://example.com/a?go-get=1: dial tcp 208.73.210.202:443: connect: connection refused)
```

How does the transitive dependency for local modules work?
Why is Go hitting example.com to bring the modules?
What is going on?

Comment: "Some bright developer thought that every module must have a dot(.) in their module name." Because some bright developer actually understood how Go imports were meant to be used - they're meant to be `go get`-able, not just arbitrary directories on disk.

Comment: @Adrian dont get mad at me! Its very individualistic policy.Just to give an example its like unless you wear a red pyjamas at the party you wont get food vs you wear anything you want..come to the party..we will give you red pyjamas and you have food then... Go assumes some-one is going to write the modules push it to the repository and I am going to work on it ... it doesnt assume (however it gives mechanism to work with it) that I can create multiple random modules on the disk without trying to push them anywhere!

Comment: Correct. That is how Go modules work. The (entirely reasonable) assumption is that any software project will have a repository. Usually the first step in any software project beyond a throw-away single-file script is to create a repository for it, so it shouldn't be a problem. If you're making a complex, multi-module, inter-dependent software project and you don't have a repository, the problem isn't Go modules' support for arbitrary local modules, it's that you're not using source control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Go Wiki: Modules: go.mod](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#gomod)

> `exclude` and `replace` directives only operate on the current (“main”) module. **`exclude` and `replace` directives in modules other than the main module are ignored when building the main module.** The `replace` and `exclude` statements, therefore, allow the main module complete control over its own build, without also being subject to complete control by dependencies. (See FAQ [below](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive) for a discussion of when to use a `replace` directive).

And also in [Command go: The main module and the build list:](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-The_main_module_and_the_build_list)

> The main module's go.mod file defines the precise set of packages available for use by the go command, through require, replace, and exclude statements. Dependency modules, found by following require statements, also contribute to the definition of that set of packages, but only through their go.mod files' require statements: **any replace and exclude statements in dependency modules are ignored**. The replace and exclude statements therefore allow the main module complete control over its own build, without also being subject to complete control by dependencies.

Package `a` is not found when building the module `c`, so the `go` tool tries to resolve it, tries to download it. That's why it tries to interpret the package name as something that should start with a host name.

You do not need to rename package `a` to `example.com/a`, but you must add a `replace` directive to `c`'s `go.mod` where you tell where the package `a` is located.

Comment: thanks for the solution...but is this even viable? I thought the whole idea of import is that I as a developer would be abstracted away from all the dependencies of the module I am importing. Lets say I have a big project where there are 10-12 hierarchy and I want to consume the latest . I have to include each of my imported libraries' dependencies!

Comment: @deepg This is only needed if the modules you use have `replace` directives which otherwise should only be used for testing / local development. When you publish a module, it should have no dependencies on local packages not being part of the module. Using such modules you have nothing to do: you just import them and the `go` tool and module system resolves all dependencies automatically.

Comment: Thanks @icza for the detailed explanation. It really helped. Just to be honest . Go brings very new perspective from development POV. However the documentation fails to highlight the nuances of it. Don't get me wrong there are loads of information lurking within those lines , but its like a pearl within an ocean.

Comment: @deepg There are a lot to be covered, so a single, few page documentation cannot possible cover everything anybody would ever need. The official home page is always a good starting point, which also covers this (added as the 2nd quote). Stackoverflow is also a good place to ask what you cannot find or understand.